# How to execute a JPAQuery with pagination using Spring Data and QueryDSL

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have this request working good with `queryDSL` :

```
 Iterable<AO> query_result = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(ao)
            .leftJoin( ao.lots , lot )
            .leftJoin( ao.acs , ac )
              .where(where).distinct()
                .list(ao);
```

But what is its equivalent if we use it with `spring data jpa`

```
ao_respository.findAll(Predicate arg0, Pageable arg1);
```

Because i want to return a `Page` and just with `querydsl` it doesn't implement `Page` without `spring data jpa`.

I try to put my `where` in `Predicate arg0` but i got this exception

```
Undeclared path 'lot '. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it
```

where `lot` is declared as `QLot lot = QLot.lot;`

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer. How about rephrasing your question to something like "How to execute a JPAQuery with pagination using Spring Data and QueryDSL".... I know you have tags, but the title isn't helping for getting answers.

Comment: I propose a solution but there is a warning at the end

Answer (score 7):

Returning a `Page`:

```
JPAQuery query = 
    ...
    .orderBy(getOrderSpecifiers(pageable, MyEntity.class))
    .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
    .offset(pageable.getOffset());

long total = query.fetchCount();
List<MyEntity> content = query.fetch();
return new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, total);
```

And I created this function to get `OrderSpecifier`:

```
private OrderSpecifier[] getOrderSpecifiers(@NotNull Pageable pageable, @NotNull Class klass) {

    // orderVariable must match the variable of FROM
    String className = klass.getSimpleName();
    final String orderVariable = String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(className.charAt(0))).concat(className.substring(1));

    return pageable.getSort().stream()
            .map(order -> new OrderSpecifier(
                    Order.valueOf(order.getDirection().toString()),
                    new PathBuilder(klass, orderVariable).get(order.getProperty()))
            )
            .toArray(OrderSpecifier[]::new);
}
```

Comment: fetchCount is deprecated now

Answer (score 5):

I created my own Page class and executed the query like this:

```
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(ao)               
            .leftJoin( .. ).fetch()
            .leftJoin( .. ).fetch()
            ...
            .where(where)




    MaPage<AO> page = new MaPage<AO>();
    page.number = pageNumber+1;

    page.content = query.offset(pageNumber*pageSize).limit(pageSize).list(ao);

    page.totalResult = query.count();
```

My Page class:

```
public class MaPage<T> {

    public List<T> content;
    public int number;
    public Long totalResult;
    public Long totalPages;
    ...
}
```

It works but I got this warning

> nov. 21, 2014 6:48:54 AM
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl list WARN:
>   HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch;
>   applying in memory!

Comment: When you join fetch a collection property pagination can't be applied on the SQL level.

Comment: Yes but there is not a altenative to avoid this warning ? Because i need yo use fetch to display data on my page.

Comment: You can avoid this warning if you get rid of left join fetch and use for example batch fetching for the collection members.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working, complex query in querydsl and you want to use springdata pagination, you have to:

1. make your querydsl/repository method return `Page<T>`

   ```
    Page<YourEntity> yourSelect(Pageable aPageable)
   ```
2. use querydsl `offset` and `limit` to page your result set

   ```
   List<YourEntity>  theResultList = jpaQueryFactory
                   .select(<whatever complext jpaquery you like>)
                   .offset(aPageable.getOffset())
                   .limit(aPageable.getPageSize())
                   .fetch();
   ```
3. provide a `LongSuplier` counting all available results with respect to your query and use `PageableExecutionUtils` to return the result as `Page`

   ```
   final long theCount = jpaQueryFactory
         .selectFrom(<your select to count all results>)
         .fetchCount();

   return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(theResultList, aPageable, () -> theCount);
   ```

Comment: it would be nice to have a reference with examples